# How to upload image and show preview "without form submit"?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

I have very large form it contains 30 fields, but i need to upload image when it changes browses. like profile photo. use any using ajax, jquery or PHP.. Please give me code or some suggestions.

Comment: Is there any other best solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's no longer possible because in modern browsers

- you can't read the full path of an image from an upload field any more
- links to local resources don't work anymore

for security reasons.

Comment: ok give a suggestion how to manage this profile view? while register there is a Avatar upload, That should display in a PIC container panel.

Comment: @Navruk you could do the upload separately in an iframe, or use a Flash-based uploader like swfupload.org

Answer (score 0):

you can place file upload related content in iframe and include that iframe in main page. so on post back of file upload, you can get image path from response and show in main page.

**Main page:**

```
 <p>
                <iframe id="ifrFileUpload" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" hidefocus="true" style="text-align: left;
                    vertical-align: middle; border-style: none; margin-right: 120px; margin-bottom: 20px;
                    float: right; width: 70%; height: 40px" src="http://site.com/FileUpload">
                </iframe>

            </p>
```

**IFrame:**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="http://site.com/FileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    method="post">
 <p>   
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

 </p>
    </form>
```

and on response, you can call parent function method to show image

Comment: any way here also we are submitting the form

Comment: @Navruk - no, you're submitting the form in the iframe - not the form in your main page; this is an excellent solution for your need.